# Play a sound when the user clicks a button and then go to a different page

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio, onclick

Currently have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio id="audio" src="D:\DiscordFAQ\baba.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <!--<a onclick="PlaySound()"> Play</a> -->
    <script>
    function PlaySound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play()
      }
    </script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="PlaySound(); location.href = 'Profielfotoaanpassen.html'">Volgend Onderwerp</button> 
  </body>

</html>
```

When a user clicks the button I need it to play a sound and when the sound finishes it needs to go to a different page.

What happens right now is that the sound doesn't play because it immediately goes to the other page.

Comment: investigate the Window `onunload` or `unload` event.; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get sound length by `sound.duration` and delay redirect with `setTimeout()`. Here is complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio id="audio" src="D:\DiscordFAQ\baba.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <!--<a onclick="PlaySound()"> Play</a> -->
    <script>
      function PlaySound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play();
          setTimeout(function(){ location.href = 'Profielfotoaanpassen.html'; }, sound.duration * 1000);
      }
    </script>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="PlaySound();">Volgend Onderwerp</button> 
  </body>

</html>
```

Live demo: https://stackoverflow-play-and-redirect.glitch.me/

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<audio id="audio" src="Documents\testsite\baba.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>

<script>

function PlaySound() {
var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
sound.play();
setTimeout(function(){ location.href = 'Profielfotoaanpassen.html'; }, sound.duration * 1000);
}

</script>
    
<button type="button" onclick="PlaySound();">Volgend Onderwerp</button> 

</body>

</html>
`

It doesn't play any sound and just goes to the other page.

Comment: It is strange, for me it works. Try [this live demo](https://stackoverflow-play-and-redirect.glitch.me/). I hope it helps.